# How is HKLM\S..\CurrentVersion\Uninstall Version derived from ProductVersion property

Tags: algorithm, windows-installer, registry

I'm trying to do a deep dive to troubleshoot an intermittent problem we're experiencing with some major upgrade installs evaluating as maintenance installations when running msiexec against an msi.  MSDN gives a rundown of the [Uninstall registry key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx) and states that Version is derived from the ProductVersion property.

My question is how?  For example how does '16.48.31' get converted to '0x1030001f (271581215)'?  VersionMajor and VersionMinor are straightforward, '16' and '48' respectively.  Version, on the other hand, not so much.

The answer may not be relevatory to my problem, but I'm running out of other leads to track down.

Comment: 0x001f == 31, maximum is 65535.

Comment: I get that.  So it's one byte, one byte, two bytes rolled into a single number.  Derp.
0x1030 breaking down to:
0x10 = 16
0x30 = 48
0x001f = 31

Feeling sheepish...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely that you haven't updated both **ProductVersion** and **ProductCode** and **package code** in your update setup. This yields a **minor upgrade** instead of the desired **major upgrade**.

The **package code** should always be changed every time your setup is compiled since it is only supposed to be unique. If two MSI files have the same package code Windows installer treat them as the same file by definition, and really strange problems can result - including the behavior you are seeing.

I just want to make sure you are not using an Installshield Installscript MSI project? This is the special project type that runs Installshields GUI instead of the regular MSI GUI. The project type is riddled with problems and should not be used. Instead you should use a Basic MSI project.

Comment: Using WIX and ProductVersion gets incremented with each build. In this case the 31 in 16.48.31 is the 31st build of the 16.48 release.  We also gen a new ProductCode and package code GUID with each build.  I've looked through the MSIs using Orca and have verified that we're incrementing the version with each subsequent build.  I've also verified that the two GUIDs are unique with each MSI.

Comment: What I'm seeing, though, is that ProductState is evaluating to 5 with our major upgrades, which I guess reflects reality.  The problem being that it is registering as being in maintenance mode so a number of our custom actions relating to stopping/starting app pools and Windows services aren't getting called.